# IE 8 Jquery focus issue children inside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a color picker

```
<div id="parentdiv" class='picker-on'>

    <input id=color_picker" class="E-panel-hex focus" type="text" value="#ce5059" name="color_picker" style="background-color: rgb(221, 95, 164); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">

    <div id="picker" style="left: 669px; top: 289px;">
        <div class="farbtastic">
            <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 163);"></div>
            <div class="wheel"></div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="h-marker marker" style="left: 45px; top: 31px;"></div>
            <div class="sl-marker marker" style="left: 61px; top: 101px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

If i click on my input field the parent div 'parentdiv' gets a class picker-on

and the wheel shows up, when i click outside the color_picker div the wheel disappears in firefox width this code

```
$('.picker-on').focusout(function(){
        $('div.picker-on').removeClass('picker-on');
        $('#picker').remove();
        $('#'+thisid).trigger('change');
    });
```

you can see here how the colorpicker is build up

http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic

The problem:
Focusout function:
lose focus if I go from the wheel to the square and the div picker disappears
and if i go from the square to the wheel it also disappears.
Blur function:
Doesnt disppear at all!

i can't get the right code for this any help is welcome!

Edit: Only IE8 problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.blur()`, instead of `.focusout()`.
focusout supports event bubbling, it will fire even if a child element loses focus, that maybe your problem.

source: http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: if i use blur, it only switches when i click another input field, if i click outside the picker div it doesnt remove the div at all